# puppetserver timeout cannot find key

Tags: ssl, puppet

Fresh install on Centos (tried both 6 and 7) from the PC1 repo. Starting `puppetserver` munchs away at my RAM for a few minutes then fails with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize master with partial state; need all files or none.
Found:
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/puppet.novalocal.pem
Missing:
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/puppet.novalocal.pem
```

It seems that it is looking in the wrong directory for the public key as it appears to have been created elsewhere:

```
[chris@puppet ~]$ sudo find /etc/puppetlabs/ -name puppet.novalocal.pem
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/puppet.novalocal.pem
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys/puppet.novalocal.pem
```

I am dumbly following the [official docs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.0/reference/install_linux.html#installing-release-packages-on-yumrpm-systems). so it may mean a little correction there or in the install package

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well.
The problem is most likely that `puppet agent` ran before starting `puppetserver`.
The agent will create its key when it runs the first time, but not the CA that is required to run the server.

To solve this on that existing VM, you will need to remove those keys:

```
rm -rf /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/*
```

And then start the puppetserver again.
The server will then generate all the keys required to run.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I have no idea when the client got ran first - must have been a slip of the fingers. I would add that the `*` at the end is important. I absent-mindedly deleted the ssl dir too and had to recreate and `chown puppet` it

Comment: For future readers, this is the ticket to get this fixed: https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/SERVER-528